# Using Navigator.pop() to send an image

Tags: flutter

Using the following code:

```
  onPressed: () async {
            final route = MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) =>
                    Homepage_1(imagePath: <File>[File(widget.imagePath)]));

            Navigator.of(context).pop();
            Navigator.of(context).pop(route);
          },
          child: Text(
            'Okay',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
```

the page navigates back two, however, it does not bring the image path with it. How can I rectify this code?

Comment: The `pop` method takes an argument and returns to the previous page. Use `push` instead of pop in `Navigator.of(context).pop(route);`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using pop you can do somethings like this:

```
// in route 1
Navigator.push(
   Route2(
      onClose: (image) { /* you can use your image here */ }
   )
)

// in route 2

Navigator.push(
   Route3(
      onClose: (image) {
          Navigator.of(context).pop()
          widget.onClose(image);
      }
   )
)

// in route 3

onPressed: () {
  Navigator.of(context).pop()
  widget.onClose(image);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `pop()` twice you can try `pushAndRemoveUntil`

```
Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                                  return Homepage_1(imagePath: <File>[File(widget.imagePath)]));
                                }), (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```